# Need help in Kendo Window UI control

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am working on a councelor portal which is a part of our project in company and my boss advised me to use kendow windo pop control for popups on certain links.

I have done it by using the kendo application control but a little problem arouse which makes my look and feel bad a little.

we got links on one page and our application is supposed to show use popup window when any of the link will be clicked but when I actually runs the page then a popup kendo window comes first and when I minimize it or close it then link starts working according to our desire.

I am sure there is some problem with jquery code which shows the popup window on document.ready(function(){}); but it should work when a link is clicked.

I am posting my code here please help me out to make it more refined and good looking

```
var window = $("#window"),
                        undo = $("#undo")
                                .bind("click", function () {
                                    window.data("kendoWindow").open();
                                    window.data("kendoWindow").center();
                                    undo.hide();
                                });




var onClose = function () {
    undo.show();
}

if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {
    window.kendoWindow({
        width: "600px",
        height: "500px",
        draggable: false,
        actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
        resizable: false,
        title: "Report Activity",
        content: "../../AlertCounselor.htm",
        close: onClose
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="window"></div>

            <label id="undo" style="display:none; width:200px;" class="k-group" ><a href="#">Alert Counselor</a></label>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the window to be displayed when the document is loaded, you should specify `visible: false` in the initialization (check documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#visible-booleandefault) ).

Lets assume that you have the following link:

```
<a href="#" id="open">Click here for opening the window and not before</a>
```

Then define the window as:

```
var myWindow = window.kendoWindow({
    visible  : false,
    width    : "600px",
    height   : "500px",
    draggable: false,
    actions  : ["Minimize", "Maximize", "Close"],
    resizable: false,
    title    : "Report Activity",
    content  : "../../AlertCounselor.htm",
    close    : onClose
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

This should leave the window closed waiting for something else that open it.

Finally define a `click` event handler for the link:

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
    myWindow.open();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro but the thing is when I apply in property then window disappear even the link is not there.

Comment: I want to show this window on a link click which is displayed in my html page. when I refresh the page windows comes first and after closing the window links appear and things gets straight after that. I dont want user to see a window which he did not ask for without clicking anything ..

Comment: I've modified the answer for dealing with the click on the link. See if this is what you want.